# Why is angular response.headers different from browser dev-tools response headers?

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies

```
        this.http.post(this.url+"/login",formData).subscribe(
        (response: any)=>{
        console.log(response.headers);
        const cookies: string | null = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie');
        // console.log(response.headers);
        console.log(cookies);
        if (cookies) {
            const parsedCookies = cookies.split(';').map(cookie => cookie.trim());
            for (const cookie of parsedCookies) {
                const [name, value] = cookie.split('=');
                document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
            }
        }
    }
    );
```

I console logged the response header and I get an error because it is null, but in the browser dev-tools it is not null.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz7Om.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLO1E.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `Set-Cookie` header because [it is filtered out by your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie).

Also the code code block below is completely useless even if you could access this header because `Set-Cookie` automatically **sets cookies** for you.

```
if (cookies) {
            const parsedCookies = cookies.split(';').map(cookie => cookie.trim());
            for (const cookie of parsedCookies) {
                const [name, value] = cookie.split('=');
                document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
            }
        }
```

Your response might be `null` because backend returned zero bytes response (actually, in this case it had to be HTTP 204 code, not HTTP 200 but this is a different topic).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I still have few questions. If Set-Cookie automatically sets cookie for you then why in dev tools in cookies section there is no cookie saved? Shouldn't there be a cookie after sending the request if the request is successfull? My login system works perfectly in postman, but it does not work with angular and the reason for this I think is that the cookie is not automatically saved.

Comment: @AndreiBerendea hard to say, there are many reasons for that. For example, (1) cookies are not set for localhost (2) cookies are set but for api domain (i.e., for domain from `this.url`, not your angular app's domain)